# How can I get all OSM ways and nodes tagged amenity, plus way nodes using the Overpass API?

Tags: api, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to get all the ways and nodes with an 'amenity' key, which works okay with a union, but I also need the nodes that make up a way, and the recurse tag isn't working as expected:

```
<osm-script>
<union>
<query type="way">
  <has-kv k="amenity" regv="."/>
  <bbox-query s="%s" w="%s" n="%s" e="%s"/>
</query>

<query type="node">
  <has-kv k="amenity" regv="."/>
  <bbox-query s="%s" w="%s" n="%s" e="%s"/>
</query>
</union>
<recurse type="way-node" />
<print/></osm-script>
```

The %s are placeholders.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With your code, the results of the way query are *replaced* by the results of the recursion. Therefore, you should have the (usually untagged) nodes of the amenity ways in your output, but not the ways themselves.

Putting these in a union together, however, means that both the ways and their node end up in your output:

```
<osm-script>
  <union>
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="amenity"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="amenity"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <recurse type="way-node" />   
  </union>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

The {{bbox}} are placeholders for multiple parameters as in your example. If you want to test the modified query yourself, try [this Overpass Turbo link](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/b5).

(Also note that you can omit the catch-all regv parameters.)